# kcfinder unable to access or create thumbnails folder

Tags: php, kcfinder

Im using the KCfinder everything worked perfectly on localhost but once transferred onto live server im now getting the error

```
cannot access or create the thumbnails folder
```

i have deleted the original thumbnail folder create a new one with different name change the settings and its still showing,

I have chmod the folders to 755 and still no luck, does anyone have any experience with this error? and a solution on how to fix? as its driving me insane.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed, Unsure what i did tho?

just messed with the configuration file then reverted everything back to normal ???